# Instant Checkbox update on sql rows with ajax and jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Example of what I want:
[image]

Hi i want on each row to update instant the checkbox with value 1 when checked and 0 when not checked.
I've make some steps and already taken in a URL via post the values, but I see that updates only on the first row of my table.  I think it must have some foreach or loop on ajax to take value to other rows?
This value will export as a URL querystring (ischeck) to an extrnal URL to take import on my function to make the sql query to update the value.

Here is the javascript that for sure want changes about loop that I haven't put on charges.php.

```
 <script>
        $(function($) {
            var arr = [];
            $('input.checkbox').on('change', function() {

                var id = "<?php echo $charge['id'] ?>";

                var check_active = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

                var check_id = $('[id^="checked-]');


                arr.push(check_active);
                var url = "ajax_ischeck.php?id=" + id + "&ischeked=" + check_active;
                console.log("url", url);

                if (this.checked) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: 'html',

                        success: function(response) {


                        },



                    });

                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the table with the input checkbox sry its little big the checkbox is down to last lines on Charges.php:

```
<tbody>
                <?php foreach ($showcharge as $charge) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($charge['created_at']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($charge['tasks']); ?> </td>
                        <th width="5%"><?php if (empty($charge['taskcharges'])) {
                                            echo "Free";
                                        } else {
                                            echo htmlspecialchars($charge['taskcharges'] . "\xE2\x82\xAc");
                                        } ?></th>
                        <th width="5%"><?php
                                        if (empty($charge['payment'])) {
                                            echo htmlspecialchars($charge['payment']);
                                        } else {
                                            echo htmlspecialchars($charge['payment'] . "\xE2\x82\xAc");
                                        }

                                        ?>


                        </th>
                        <th width="5%" id="balance"><?= htmlspecialchars($charge['balance'] . "\xE2\x82\xAc") ?></th>

                        <th width="10%"><?php if (($charge['payment_date'] == 0000 - 00 - 00)) {
                                            echo "";
                                        } else {

                                            echo htmlspecialchars($charge['payment_date']);
                                        } ?></th>
                        <th width="10%"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($charge['admin']); ?></th>
                        <th width="15%"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($charge['comments']); ?></th>
                        <td class="mytd">

                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <a href="editcharge.php?id=<?php echo $charge['id'];
                                                            echo '&custid=' . $customer['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-info " role=" button " aria-disabled=" true">Edit</a>

                            </form>
                            <form id="delete-<?php echo $charge['id'] ?>" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_to_delete" value="<?php echo $charge['id']  ?>" />
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name=" delete" value="delete" />
                            </form>

                            <script>
                                $("#delete").submit(function() {
                                    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                                });
                            </script>

                        </td>

                          <th width="7%"> <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked value="1" id="checked-1" name="checbox"> <label> Success </label> </input> </th>



                    </tr>

                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
```

The ajax_ischeck.php that gets data from charges.php post :

```
<?php include('dataprocess.php'); ?>
<?php include('config/pdo_connect.php'); ?>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$ischeck = $_GET['ischeck'];

if(isset($_GET["ischeck"])){
  
    Data::ischecked($id, $ischeck);
}
```

and the sql query:

```
public static function ischecked ($id, $ischeck)

    {

        $sql = "UPDATE charges SET 
            
            
            
            ischecked='$ischeck'
            
            WHERE id=$id";

        $statement = conn()->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        /*   echo $sql;
            die();  */

        if (!$statement) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        }

    }
```

Comment: This won 't work because you 're using invalid HTML. You can only use an ID once in an HTML document. An ID attribute has to be unique in the whole document. Chose an ID attribute like `id="checked-1"` and so on. The number in the id attribute is the primary key of the rowset in the database. You can select these id attributes with the css selector `$('[id^="checked-]')` (all elements that have an id attribute that begins with "checked-").

Comment: @Marcel I change the value on html to id="checked-1" and now i can see that i take post and from rows above! but with same url id such as url ajax_ischeck.php?id=624&ischeked=1 the first id is the same, can you be more specific whre can i add the $('[id^="checked-]') on my javascript please ? i think im near to fix my problem.

Comment: @Marcel I update the code with the changes that you suggest me, except the $('[id^="checked-]') that i dont know the whey must be set